# Apache 2.4 config to work with 2.2

Tags: apache-2.2, apache-2.4

I have upgraded to Apache 2.4 and I needed to change all

```
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
```

to

```
Require all granted
```

however, that caused those virtual host files to stop working on Apache 2.2.

Is there a way to write some `IF` in the configuration to get get same virtual host file to work for both versions?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use `mod_version` ([link](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_version.html))

```
<IfVersion >= 2.4>
     Require all granted
</IfVersion>
<IfVersion < 2.4>
     Order allow,deny
     Allow from all
</IfVersion>
```

Comment: Thanks, this works too! Was wondering - would I be better off using IfVersion or IfModule as outlined in the answer I found? Thanks.

Comment: My approach is the more flexible when it comes to versions. With the `mod_authz_core` version you just can check this is 2.4, but no sub versions and likely not that it might be 2.6 at some point. So I would prefer `mod_version` and only fall back to the other approach if that wouldn't be available.

Comment: Hm... actually I have to retract my earlier comment - this does not work in 2.2... I get following error:
Invalid command '<IfVersion', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration.. am I doing something wrong?

Comment: You have to make sure mod_version is installed and activated. Depending on your system, maybe you have to install a package.

Comment: OK, I am kind of torn... answer that uses `IfModule` does not require any additional packages...

Comment: It should be availabe already, you need to activate it. It would help if you would finally add some details about your environment to the question (e.g. the OS used and how you upgraded Apache). Use the edit button for this.

Answer (score 4):

While waiting for an answer I seem to have found the solution:

```
<IfModule mod_authz_core.c>
   # Apache 2.4
   Require all granted
</IfModule>
<IfModule !mod_authz_core.c>
   # Apache 2.2
   Order deny,allow
   Allow from all
</IfModule>
```

Apparently you can check for existence of specific modules and make Apache2 do stuff accordingly.